# How to unwrap the elements of an Array in Swift? (ie. Array<Int?> as Array<Int>)

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say I have an Array of String and I want to map it to an Array of Int
I can use the map function:

```
var arrayOfStrings: Array = ["0", "a"]
let numbersOptional = arrayOfStrings.map { $0.toInt() }
// numbersOptional = "[Optional(0), nil]"
```

Numbers is now an Array of Int?, but I want an Array of Int.
I know I can do this:

```
let numbers = arrayOfStrings.map { $0.toInt() }.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
// numbers = [0]
```

But that doesn't seem very swift. Converting from the Array of Int? to Array of Int requires calling both filter and map with pretty much boilerplate stuff. Is there a more swift way to do this?

Comment: How do you expect "a" to map to an `Int`?

Comment: @Zaph "a".toInt() returns nil, so I want it filtered out of my array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["0", "a", "1"]
let numbersOnly = arrayOfStrings.flatMap { Int($0) }

print(numbersOnly)   // [0,1]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** As of Swift 1.2, there's a built-in `flatMap` method for arrays, but it doesn't accept `Optional`s, so the helper below is still useful.

---

I like using a helper `flatMap` function for that sort of things, just like Scala's `flatMap` method on collections (which can consider an Scala `Option` as a collection of either 0 or 1 element, roughly spoken):

```
func flatMap<C : CollectionType, T>(source: C, transform: (C.Generator.Element) -> T?) -> [T] {
    var buffer = [T]()
    for elem in source {
        if let mappedElem = transform(elem) {
            buffer.append(mappedElem)
        }
    }
    return buffer
}

let a = ["0", "a", "42"]
let b0 = map(a, { $0.toInt() }) // [Int?] - [{Some 0}, nil, {Some 42}]
let b1 = flatMap(a, { $0.toInt() }) // [Int] - [0, 42]
```

This definition of `flatMap` is rather a special case for `Optional` of what a more general `flatMap` should do:

```
func flatMap<C : CollectionType, T : CollectionType>(source: C, transform: (C.Generator.Element) -> T) -> [T.Generator.Element] {
    var buffer = [T.Generator.Element]()
    for elem in source {
        buffer.extend(transform(elem))
    }
    return buffer
}
```

where we'd get

```
let b2 = flatMap(a, { [$0, $0, $0] }) // [String] - ["0", "0", "0", "a", "a", "a", "42", "42", "42"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `reduce` to build the new array might be more idiomatic

```
func filterInt(a: Array<String>) -> Array<Int> {
    return a.reduce(Array<Int>()) {
        var a = $0
        if let x = $1.toInt() {
            a.append(x)
        }
        return a
    }
}
```

Example

```
filterInt(["0", "a", "42"]) // [0, 42]
```

What you would really want is a `collect` (`map` + `filter`) method. Given the specific filter you need to apply, in this case even a `flatMap` would work (see Jean-Philippe's answer). Too bad both methods are not provided by the swift standard library.

Comment: It's a bit confusing when you use 'a' as both a parameter name and a variable name.

Comment: looks to me like a new array is created for every appended item, with all the copying overhead .. O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

There’s no good builtin Swift standard library way to do this.  However, Haskell has a function, `mapMaybe`, that does what you’re looking for (assuming you just want to ditch nil values).  Here’s an equivalent in Swift:

```
func mapSome<S: SequenceType, D: ExtensibleCollectionType>
  (source: S, transform: (S.Generator.Element)->D.Generator.Element?)
  -> D {
        var result = D()
        for x in source {
            if let y = transform(x) {
                result.append(y)
            }
        }
        return result
}

// version that defaults to returning an array if unspecified
func mapSome<S: SequenceType, T>
  (source: S, transform: (S.Generator.Element)->T?) -> [T] {
    return mapSome(source, transform)
}

let s = ["1","2","elephant"]
mapSome(s) { $0.toInt() }  // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `reduce`, it's more flexible:

```
var arrayOfStrings: Array = ["0", "a"]
let numbersOptional = arrayOfStrings.reduce([Int]()) { acc, str in
  if let i = str.toInt() {
    return acc + [i]
  }

  return acc
}
```