# Unwrap Sparse Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, xcode6.1

I'd like to write an extension for `Array` which safely returns an unwrapped version of itself.

I can do it with a generic method like so:

```
func unwrapElements<T>(array: [T?]) -> [T] {
    let filtered: [T?] = array.filter{ $0 != nil }
    let unwrapped: [T] = filtered.map { $0! }
    return unwrapped
}
```

And I can call it like this:

```
let sparseNames: [String?] = ["alice", "bob", nil, "doug", nil, nil, "george", "hubert"]
let names: [String] = unwrapElements(sparseNames)
```

where `names` ends up being `["alice", "bob", "doug", "george", "hubert"]` and is safe to iterate and work with each element.

However, I want to call it like this:

```
let names = sparseNames.unwrapElements()
```

I've seen a few similar questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163741/how-to-unwrap-the-elements-of-an-array-in-swift-ie-arrayint-as-arrayint)) but they don't address how to create the method as an extension.

---

(this is tagged with Xcode6.1 to denote the version of Swift I'm using)

---

Note: Swift 1.2 Beta 3 has introduced the `flatMap` function which helps with optionally chaining arrays.  See this excellent [blog post here](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/03/13/changes-to-the-swift-standard-library-in-1-2-betas-2-and-3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this right now in Swift. To add that function as an extension to `Array`, you'd have to mark somehow that it's only callable with *certain kinds of arrays*: those with optional values as the subtype. Unfortunately, you can't further specialize a generic type, so global functions are the only way possible.

This is the same reason `Array` has a `sort` method that takes a comparison function as a parameter, but it doesn't have a `sort` that "just works" if the array is full of `Comparable` members - to get that kind of function, you have to look at the top-level sort:

```
func sort<T : Comparable>(inout array: [T])
```

Comment: well boo.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064644/how-to-determine-if-a-generic-is-an-optional-in-swift) seemed to indicate there might be a method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `filter` and `map` for that?

```
let array: [String?] = ["Hello", nil, "World"]

let unwrapped = array.map{$0 ?? nil}.filter{$0 != nil}.map{$0!}

println("unwrapped: \(unwrapped)")
// prints "unwrapped: [Hello, World]"
```

The first `map` uses the Nil Coalescing Operator to unwrap if possible. Although, I return `nil` regardless since the following filter removes all `nil` values. The last `map` does the actual unwrapping.

Comment: So this is interesting, if you perform each of those steps on separate lines, the `Optional()` is never removed.  you need to add an `as! [String]` after the filtered line, which must be implied in the final `.map` ?

Comment: Do you mean as separate `let x =` statements? I tried that myself and did not have to change anything:

`let step1 = array.map{$0 ?? nil} // prints "[Optional("Hello"), nil, Optional("World")]"`

`let step2 = step1.filter{$0 != nil} // prints "[Optional("Hello"), Optional("World")]"`

`let step3 = step2.map{$0!} // prints [Hello, World]`

Comment: ah, when writing it out I missed the final `$0!`

Comment: This is exactly what `flatMap` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Here is how:

```
extension Array {
    func catOptionals<A>() -> [A] where Element == A? {
        return self.flatMap{ $0 }
    }
}
```